In the nature or in nature
" the picture shows the process of producing carbon in the nature/ in nature"
Which one is correc? I thought it's in nature, but my teacher said it's in the nature.

Your teacher is wrong. I have often seen 'in the nature' in translations from other European languages such as German, where really 'in nature' or even 'in the country' would be idiomatic English.

Please use proper punctuation. This is not a texting site. Your question is practically illegible.

Your teacher is wrong and you are correct.
It is "the process of producing carbon in nature" - meaning a natural process.
However, we say: "in the nature of things", meaning "normally", or "the way things/situations typically develop".
PS: However, because the teacher is still the teacher even when wrong, be sure to acquaint yourself with the meaning of the words "tact" and "discretion" before pointing it out.
